# Python: Add vwap to candlestick chart

Tags: python, candlestick-chart

I have tried to figure this out but unable to come up with an idea. I'm plotting OHlC candlestick using plotly. I also have vwap calculated on the same csv. How do I plot the vwap on the same graph as the candlestick chart  like

[image: as shown here]

Is there any resources, I can check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the average price of the trading volume load, I used the [following page](https://analyzingalpha.com/vwap) as a reference. The [mpf library](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance) can be found here and the instructions for adding plots can be found [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import mplfinance as mpf

df = yf.download("AAPL", start="2021-01-01", end="2021-07-01")

v = df['Volume'].values
tp = (df['Low'] + df['Close'] + df['High']).div(3).values
df = df.assign(vwap=(tp * v).cumsum() / v.cumsum())

adp = mpf.make_addplot(df['vwap'], type='line')
mpf.plot(df, figratio=(8,4), type='candle', addplot=adp, volume=True, style='yahoo')
```

[image]

**plotly**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = yf.download("AAPL", start="2021-01-01", end="2021-07-01")

v = df['Volume'].values
tp = (df['Low'] + df['Close'] + df['High']).div(3).values
df = df.assign(vwap=(tp * v).cumsum() / v.cumsum())


fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df.index,
                open=df['Open'],
                high=df['High'],
                low=df['Low'],
                close=df['Close'],name='AAPL')])

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['vwap'],
    mode='lines',
    name='vwap', 
    line=dict(color='royalblue',width=2)
))

fig.update_layout(
    height=600
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: There was another [page](https://school.stockcharts.com/doku.php?id=technical_indicators:vwap_intraday), please refer to it. If my answer was helpful to you, please click the check mark to accept the answer.

Comment: Since you may not be familiar with Mplfinance, I have added an example using plotly as an answer. This is also a modification of the example in the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/candlestick-charts/#simple-candlestick-with-pandas).